# How to make a test optional in pytest?

Tags: pytest

I have an integration test using another service and I want this to be able to fail if the service is down without blocking the CI pipeline.

I found `@pytest.mark.optional` on the internet however I could not find it in the [official docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#pytest-mark-filterwarnings). What is the right way to make a test fail with just a warning?

Comment: Perhaps skipping the test if the service is down would be an option. You can skip pytest tests based on conditions with `skipif` marker.

Comment: `@pytest.mark.skipif(service_check_failed(), reason='...')`